# Openquery through Oledb driver for DB2 slows down after a while - reboot only solution?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, linked-server, oledb

We have several sql servers that read from a db2 database on an as400 via Openquery to a linked server using the Microsoft oledb driver for db2 v5. One sql instance had a problem where its selects were running much slower than usual on that instance, racking up oledb wait types with unexpected durations (10-ish seconds), and the same query would run much faster in any of the other sql instances pointing to the same db2 db. All the sql servers and the as400 are in the same data center.

- A restart of the sql vm fixed the slowness problem. Seems like it cleared out the cobwebs around the oledb db2 driver.
- We’d prefer to have a solution that is less invasive than a reboot, like unloading and reloading the oledb db2 driver. Is that possible?
- Any benefits to upgrading to v6 of the oledb db2 driver?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 Version 6.0` and probably upgrading is not the solution.

Thank you for sharing that restarting the VM fix the issue. I will try it out on my end.

Have you checked if the `Allow inprocess` is enabled?

[image]

Otherwise try to restart SQL Server only instead of the whole VM